# Why Is Wrapped Text Off by 1 Space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using a centered navbar-brand in Bootstrap 3, and when viewed on a phone sized screen, the text wraps, but the top line has a leading space, whereas the bottom does not, leading to their being misaligned.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="title-card">Testing Testing</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In this example, "title-card" sets the font-size to 2em; and navbar-brand along with navbar-header were modified to be:

```
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
    float: none;
}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Testing is not aligned with the Testing below it.]

How would one go about aligning them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `margin:0` and `padding:0` to your `#title-card`.

```
#title-card {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
```